# how to group two radio buttons for each field in a form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 8 fields in a window form, with Yes/No values for each field. so, i kept two radio buttons for each field. One of the radio button's values is "yes" and the other is "no". The problem is it allowing just one radio button to be checked for all the 8 fields.

Can someone point me in the right direction on how to do this?

Comment: Let me get it clear. You have 8 field and each field could assume a value Yes or No?

Comment: yes, i am having 8 fields and each field could assume either Yes or No. for that i kept two radio buttons with one with value "yes" and the other for "no". but for all the 8 different fields only one radio button can be checked.

Comment: Define Name property for radio box.

Answer (score 5):

Group down the `Radio` in a Container such as `Panel or Group Box` should do the trick
In your case have 4 `Container` with 2 `Radio` each.

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks sriram. but is there any other alternative instead of using a container like Panel or Group box. because i don't like to display the borders of panel or Group box.

Comment: Unfortunately no other workaround, You can set BorderStyle = BorderStyle.None to get rid of border.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to use a CheckBox for each of the 8 fields. The checkbox is intrinsically a yes/no (checked/unchecked) control (let's forget for this scenario the Undeterminate state).
Also it is easy to change the text of the checkbox to better represent the state of your field.

For example (supposing you have a checkbox that ask for deleting a previous configuration option)

```
 public void CheckBoxConfig_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if(CheckBoxConfig.Checked == true)
        CheckBoxConfig.Text = "YES - delete this option";
     else
        CheckBoxConfig.Text = "NO - leave this option";
 }
```

Also, if you like it, you could change the appearance of the CheckBox changing the property Appearance from Normal to Button. Now you have a checkbox with the same UI design of a button. When you click on that button you could change the Text of the checkbox to YES/NO based on the Checked value. Add a label to explain your condition and you have a kind of control resembling an ON/OFF switch.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the checkbox control(you will have only 8 controls and not 24 like you now have),and check its checked property,if checked(yes) if not(no),and (this is optionaly),group them nicely in a container(like groupbox).